How to configure autopep8.args in settings?
I want to configure autopep8 as formatter in Visual Studio Code for my Python files.
In the documentation of the VSC Extension in the settings section, it is stated, that I can configure autopep8 with the keyword autopep8.args. the example is:
"autopep8.args" = ["--config", "<file>"]

But I don't understand the documentation. Why is there an equal sign? In the VSC settings.json file, the configuration is in the format "key": "value". Therefore the supposed code doesn't work like this.
What I have tried then is this in my settings.json file:
    "autopep8.args": [
        "--config", "~/DjangoKurs/techmax/.pep8"
    ]

and placed a .pep8 configuration file in the corresponding folder.
But it seems that this is the wrong way to read in my configuration settings for autopep8.
How to set this up correctly?

You can set this from the extension page itself in VSCode. If go to the extensions browser on the left and then to autopep8, you will see a gear/settings icon on the line with the 'Disable' and 'Install' buttons.
Click on the gear and then Extension Settings. In the first section, Autopep8:Args click on Add item and then enter your setting. For example:
--max-line-length=120

Click OK and then you can see the following added to your user settings. (Command Palette: Preferences:Open User Settings (JSON) )
    "autopep8.args": [
    "--max-line-length=120"
]

One very confusing issue is that the formatting given on the VSCode extension page itself did not work for me. If you follow their example, you would enter something like this in the extension settings:
"--max-line-length", "120"

But that will result in the following appearing in your user settings JSON:
"autopep8.args": [
    "\"--max-line-length\", \"120\""
]

Note that you can find potentially useful information in the autopep8 log. With a python file open and in focus, you should see "{}" with a dot on the lower right side of the footer bar in VSCode. If you click on that there is a context menu from which you can open the log.
